# Updating an XTS object

Tags: r, merge, xts

I've been struggling to do something is probably horribly simple on R. What I am trying to do is to update a XTS object column using another XTS object.

Let's say I have the following XTS object, named Object1:

```
A B
2000-01-03 , 14, NA
2000-01-04 , NA, NA
2000-01-05 , 16, 100
2000-01-06 , NA, 200
```

And the following XTS object, named Object2:

```
A
2000-01-05 , 160
2000-01-06 , 20
```

I am looking for a way to update Object1 with values from Object2, having the following result:

```
A B
2000-01-03 , 14, NA
2000-01-04 , NA, NA
2000-01-05 , 160, 100
2000-01-06 , 20, 200
```

If I do merge(Object1,Object2), I will have:

```
A B A.1
2000-01-03 , 14, NA, NA
2000-01-04 , NA, NA, NA
2000-01-05 , 16, 100, 160
2000-01-06 , NA, 200, 20
```

Which is absolutely not what I'm looking for, since I am trying to update Object1$A based on Object2$A.

What am I missing here?

Here is the output of `dput(Object1)` and `dput(Object2)` to make this reproducible:

```
> dput(Object1)
structure(c(14, NA, 16, NA, NA, NA, 100, 200), .Dim = c(4L, 2L
), index = structure(c(946857600, 946944000, 947030400, 947116800
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("A", "B")), class = c("xts", "zoo"))

> dput(Object2)
structure(c(160, 20), .Dim = c(2L, 1L), index = structure(c(947030400, 
947116800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "A"), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

Comment: The `dput` information is helpful for others trying to replicate your question.

Comment: Oops, since I am absolutely new to stackoverflow, I thought I mistakenly copy pasted a code at the end of my question, so I went back and erased it as soon as I saw it... apologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subset `Object1` using the index of `Object2`

```
> Object1[index(Object2), "A"] <- Object2$A
> Object1
             A   B
2000-01-03  14  NA
2000-01-04  NA  NA
2000-01-05 160 100
2000-01-06  20 200
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works flawlessly. I also have a little issue when I use merge.

Comment: Sorry for being kinda newbish here, but how do I get to create a column "Z_test" on Object1, filled with NA values ?

Comment: @user2026971, one way would be `Object1$Z_test <- NA`

Comment: I was trying to do it in a systematic way such as Object1[, "Z_test"] , so that I could programatically create columns... Any ideas ?

Comment: I get  "Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : subscript out of bounds" when I do that..

Comment: @user2026971, how about `cnames <- colnames(Object1);Object1 <- cbind(Object1, NA);colnames(Object1) <- c(cnames, "Z_test")`