# Update an xts time series object with data from another xts object

Tags: r, matrix, time-series, xts

I'm looking for a simpler way to update an xts time series object using data in another xts object. Data for overlapping time periods & dimensions should be updated, additional time periods should be added, and missing series dimensions should be added as needed. Currently I'm using a combination of merge, subset, and assignment. Is there a way to do this in fewer steps?

### Example

Two xts times series objects with one dimension in common (y) and two time periods in common (2018 Q2 and 2018 Q3).

```r
library(xts)

t <- as.yearqtr(paste(2018, 1:4, sep = ":Q"), format = "%Y:Q%q")

short <- xts(
    matrix(1, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y"))), 
    order.by = t[2:3]
)

long <- xts(
    matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, c("y", "z"))),
    order.by = t
)
```

`short`

```
        x y
2018 Q2 1 1
2018 Q3 1 1
```

`long`

```
        y z
2018 Q1 0 0
2018 Q2 0 0
2018 Q3 0 0
2018 Q4 0 0
```

Desired result for case 1: updating `short` with `long`

```
         x  y z
2018 Q1 NA  0 0
2018 Q2  1  0 0
2018 Q3  1  0 0
2018 Q4 NA  0 0
```

Desired result for case 2: updating `long` with `short`

```
         x  y z
2018 Q1 NA  0 0
2018 Q2  1  1 0
2018 Q3  1  1 0
2018 Q4 NA  0 0
```

#### Case 1

Merge for non-overlapping dimensions, then subset and assign for overlapping dimensions (as in: [Updating an XTS object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613981/updating-an-xts-object))

```r
short2 <- short
for (j in setdiff(colnames(long), colnames(short2))) {
    short2 <- merge(short2, long[, j])
}
short3 <- short2
for (j in intersect(colnames(short3), colnames(long))) {
    short3[index(long), j] <- long[, j]
}
short3

         x y z
2018 Q1 NA 0 0
2018 Q2  1 0 0
2018 Q3  1 0 0
2018 Q4 NA 0 0
```

#### Case 2

Same approach: merge for non-overlapping series dimensions, then subset and assign for overlapping dimensions

```r
long2 <- long
for (j in setdiff(colnames(short), colnames(long2))) {
    long2 <- merge(long2, short[, j])
}
long3 <- long2
for (j in intersect(colnames(short), colnames(long3))) {
    long3[index(short), j] <- short[, j]
}
long3

        y z  x
2018 Q1 0 0 NA
2018 Q2 1 0  1
2018 Q3 1 0  1
2018 Q4 0 0 NA
```

Is there anything simpler than this two-step process? Perhaps a function or option from another package.

Comment: I'd like to find a solution that uses time series objects rather than data frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way in `R` to `merge` while assigning priorities to columns that share the same name. I had a similar question a while ago. `R` must produce unique column names by default. You can directly assign columns a common name afterward using `setNames`, but `R` will always assign unique names (see `?make.names` for some explanation). This is not recommended though as it will make actions after that much more complicated.

Manipulating `ts` and `xts` objects is also complicated. It can be done, but isn't really worth the time. It's best to convert to `data.frame` or `tibble` and do your business in those formats, then convert back.

The following is a `tidyverse` solution and also uses the `timetk` package.

```
library(xts)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)

xts::merge.xts(long, short) %>% #merge xts objects using merge.xts
  timetk::tk_tbl() %>% #convert xts object to tibble
  dplyr::mutate(y = dplyr::coalesce(y.1, y)) %>% #replace y with coalesced y & y.1
  dplyr::select(-y.1) %>% #deselect y.1
  timetk::tk_xts(silent = T) #convert back to xts

        y z  x
2018 Q1 0 0 NA
2018 Q2 1 0  1
2018 Q3 1 0  1
2018 Q4 0 0 NA
```

Comment: It seems like there is no simple way to do this within xts. Data frame-based solutions are probably the best way to go